# Shell: Filter list by array of sed expressions

Tags: bash, zsh

I have a list like this:

```
> echo $candidates
ENV-NONPROD-SANDBOX
ENV-NONPROD-SANDBOX-SECRETS
ENV-NONPROD-DEMO
ENV-NONPROD-DEMO-SECRETS
ENV-PROD-EU
ENV-PROD-EU-SECRETS
ENV-PROD-US
ENV-PROD-US-SECRETS
```

I also have a dynamically created list of expressions which I want to apply as filters (AND) to narrow that list to possible candidates:

```bash
$ filters=('/-SECRETS/!d' '/-NONPROD/!d') # static exanmple
```

Then I concatenate this and try to apply, but that does not work:

```bash
$ filterParam=$(printf "-e '%s' " "${filters[@]}")
$ echo $filterParam
-e "/-SECRETS/!d" -e "/-NONPROD/!d"

$ echo "$candidates" | sed $filterParam
sed: 1: " '/-SECRETS/\!d'  ...": invalid command code '
```

The strange thing: If I execute it manually, it works!

```bash
> echo "$candidates" | sed -e "/-SECRETS/!d" -e "/-NONPROD/!d"
ENV-NONPROD-SANDBOX-SECRETS
ENV-NONPROD-DEMO-SECRETS
```

I execute this on macOS and `zsh 5.8.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin21.0)`

Comment: `and zsh` but you tagged bash, are you using bash __or__ zsh?

Comment: Well, it should work on both. I can add the zsh tag.

Comment: Don't put much effort into finding code which works identical for bash and zsh. The shells are simply too different. Actually, even the few lines you posted have different effect in bash and zsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> filterParam=$(printf "-e '%s' "
> ```

No, you can't store command line arguments in variables. Read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 .

You can use bash arrays, *which you already use* to store filters, so just use them:

```
sedargs=()
for i in "${filters[@]}"; do
   sedargs+=(-e "$i")
done
sed "${sedargs[@]}"
```

But `sed` is `sed`, just join array elements with a newline or a semicolon, which delimits `sed` expressions:

```
sed "$(printf "%s\n" "${filters[@]}")"
```

Comment: The second sed command skips the `-e`, correct? My sed also don't know something about `S{}` like in the first command.

Comment: `skips the -e, correct?` ? Yes, you can specify if you want to. `My sed also don't know something about S{} like in the first command` A typo, should be `${`

Answer (score 1):

When you do a

```
sed $filterParam
```

in **zsh**, `sed` is invoked with **one single** argument, which is the content of the variable `filterParam`. `sed` does not know how to handle this.

If you would type the parameters explicitly, i.e.

```
sed -e "/-SECRETS/!d" -e "/-NONPROD/!d"
```

`sed` is invoked with **four** arguments, and this is what `sed` understands.

In **bash**, in the command

```
sed $filterParam
```

the value of `filterParam` would be split at the spaces and each "word" would be passed as a separate argument. In your concrete setting, this would make have `sed` receive 4 arguments.

Comment: You can use `sed ${=filterParam}` to emulate sh/bash word splitting behavior.

Comment: @Shawn : Correct. However relying on word splitting in this case is not a good idea anyway. It would break as soon as as one of the "arguments" for sed themselves contain spaces. The whole approach of the OP is flawed, but since the OP doesn't seem to even make up his mind, whether to go with zsh or with bash (note his comment, and the fact that the question is also tagged by bash), it is hard to recommend anything. With my answer, I just wanted to make the OP understand, what's going on in his code.

Comment: Oh, yeah. An array is a much better approach here. No argument with that.